# Can't upload file and data in same request in Flask test

Tags: python, flask, python-3.4, flask-testing

Hi i'm trying to test and endpoint that will need a file and some values, when i upload only the file there is not problem, but when i add the values it throws:

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

my code is like this:

```
headers = {'content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
response = self.client.post(base_url, headers=headers, data=dict(
some_value='test', some_other_value=False, image=(BytesIO(self.test_image), 'image.png'))
```

if i do this it works:

```
headers = {'content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
    response = self.client.post(base_url, headers=headers, data=dict(
    image=(BytesIO(self.test_image), 'image.png'))
```

Comment: BytesIO only accepts binary data as input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what it have to be with anything of that but, when I changed from False in a value to 'false' it worked.

Comment: This is probably because it only accepts valid json strings